# conditional loop in python mustache

Tags: python, mustache

I have an object like this:

```
{ "Items" : [ "One", "Two", "Three" ],}
```

which is, sadly, sometimes:

```
{ "Items" : [],}
```

In Javascript's Mustache, I can conditionally render Items 2 ways:

```
{{#Items.length}}
   <ul>
   {{#Items}}
      <li>{{.}}></li>
   {{^Items}}
   </ul>
{{/Items.length}}

{{#Items.0}}
   <ul>
   {{#Items}}
      <li>{{.}}></li>
   {{^Items}}
   </ul>
{{/Items.0}}
```

Neither of those options seem available in the Python implementation.

Does anyone know of a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround (pass `bool(obj['Items'])` to `render`):

```
>>> import pystache
>>> tmpl = '''{{#has_item}}
...     <ul>
...         {{#Items}}
...         <li>{{.}}</li>
...         {{/Items}}
...     </ul>
... {{/has_item}}'''
>>> obj = {"Items": [ "One", "Two", "Three" ]}
>>> print pystache.render(tmpl, has_item=bool(obj['Items']), **obj)
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>

>>> obj = {"Items": []}
>>> print pystache.render(tmpl, has_item=bool(obj['Items']), **obj)

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
{{#Items.__len__()}}
{{/Items.__len__()}}
```

the same way you are using length in the Javascript example.